# How to use SVG in LESS

Tags: css, svg, less

I'm trying to use inline SVG (inline is very important for this project as it needs to be easily portable in a single css file) and I've decided to use LESS.  I found this page http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2012/09/base64-encoded-svg-gradient-backgrounds-in-less/ which talks about a way to do this.  However I can't seem to get this to work.  I'm using PHPStorm with a LESS Compiler plugin and it throws a Syntax error...

```
3:13:14 PM LESS CSS Compiler Error: filters.less: Syntax Error: JavaScript evaluation error: `(function(a,b,c){function e(a){a=a.replace(/\r\n/g,'\n');var b='';for(var c=0;c127&&d>6|192);b+=String.fromCharCode(d&63|128)}else{b+=String.fromCharCode(d>>12|224);b+=String.fromCharCode(d>>6&63|128);b+=String.fromCharCode(d&63|128)}}return b}function f(a){var b='';var c,f,g,h,i,j,l;var m=0;a=e(a);while(m>2;i=(c&3)>4;j=(f&15)>6;l=g&63;if(isNaN(f)){j=l=64}else if(isNaN(g)){l=64}b=b+d.charAt(h)+d.charAt(i)+d.charAt(j)+d.charAt(l)}return b}var d='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';return a+f(b)+c})('url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,','#grayscale',')')` (line 30, column 2) near
.blurToClear {
  .blur();
} (show balloon)
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.blur (@level: 3px) {
  @svg: ~"<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='blur'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='@level' /></filter></svg>#grayscale";

  /* To change level of blur, adjust all "3" to a different number */
  filter: blur(@level);
  -webkit-filter: blur(@level);
  -moz-filter: blur(@level);
  -o-filter: blur(@level);
  -ms-filter: blur(@level);
  .base64DataUriBackground(@svg);
}


.clearToBlur:hover,
.blurToClear {
  .blur();
}

//encode SVG xml as base 64
//http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2012/09/base64-encoded-svg-gradient-backgrounds-in-less/
.base64DataUriBackground (@encode, @property: ~"filter", @type: ~"image/svg+xml") {
  @dataUriPrefix: ~"url(data:@{type};base64,";
  @dataUriSuffix: ~")";

  // with btoa()
  //@b64DataUri: ~`(function(a,b,c){return a+btoa(b)+c})('@{dataUriPrefix}','@{encode}','@{dataUriSuffix}')`;

  // without
  @b64DataUri: ~`(function(a,b,c){function e(a){a=a.replace(/\r\n/g,'\n');var b='';for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++){var d=a.charCodeAt(c);if(d<128){b+=String.fromCharCode(d)}else if(d>127&&d<2048){b+=String.fromCharCode(d>>6|192);b+=String.fromCharCode(d&63|128)}else{b+=String.fromCharCode(d>>12|224);b+=String.fromCharCode(d>>6&63|128);b+=String.fromCharCode(d&63|128)}}return b}function f(a){var b='';var c,f,g,h,i,j,l;var m=0;a=e(a);while(m<a.length){c=a.charCodeAt(m++);f=a.charCodeAt(m++);g=a.charCodeAt(m++);h=c>>2;i=(c&3)<<4|f>>4;j=(f&15)<<2|g>>6;l=g&63;if(isNaN(f)){j=l=64}else if(isNaN(g)){l=64}b=b+d.charAt(h)+d.charAt(i)+d.charAt(j)+d.charAt(l)}return b}var d='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';return a+f(b)+c})('@{dataUriPrefix}','@{encode}','@{dataUriSuffix}')`;

  @property: @b64DataUri;
}
```

Any advice on how to integrate SVG with LESS?  Is it possible?  I've tried the `with btoa()` method as well and it threw the same error.

**Update ----------------------------------------------------------**
I've tried putting the SVG in directly.  When I do this...

```
.blur (@level: 3px) {
  //@svg: ~"<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='blur'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='@level' /></filter></svg>#grayscale";

  /* To change level of blur, adjust all "3" to a different number */
  filter: blur(@level);
  -webkit-filter: blur(@level);
  -moz-filter: blur(@level);
  -o-filter: blur(@level);
  -ms-filter: blur(@level);
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='blur'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='3' /></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}
```

I get this...

```
.clearToBlur:hover,
.blurToClear {
  /* To change level of blur, adjust all "3" to a different number */

  filter: blur(3px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to directly store base64 encoded data?

Comment: @feeela Yes I have, take a look above.  I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

There are two big differences between your code and that of the site you reference:

First, you are trying to set the `svg` on a `filter` property, when the solution in the site is setting it as the base `background` property for IE9 and keeping the `filter` as a default for IE8 and under.

Second, related to the first, this is not so much an issue of SVG and LESS, as it is SVG use in a `filter`. I do not believe the Microsoft `filter` property works with `svg` at all in the way you are trying to do it. You are wanting to blur an element, not do a background change. I am unaware of a way to do that with SVG in pure css. However, "why" do you need to? Can you not set for IE a [blur filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532979%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?